# Format 17 digit number/text in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to use cell format to 17 digit number. I have data in cells (Basically it is birth certificate numbers) like `12345678901234567` and I want to format it like `1234 56 78 90 12 34 567` . It is flexible to store data as number or text. I have tried
`0000 00 00 00 00 00 000` as cell custom format but it changing last two digits to zero `0`. I have also tried

```
####\ ##\ ##\ ##\ ##\ ##\ ###
```

Is there any chance to use cell formatting to get my desired output format?

Comment: With a formula, yes. But not with cell formatting, since you have more than 15 digits and so such a string cannot be interpreted as a number.

Comment: Cell formatting not working in any means due to IEEE 754 specifications, tried using `TEXTJOIN()` & `MID()` provided those 17 digit numbers are formatted as text then `=TEXTJOIN(" ",,MID(A1,{1,5,7,9,11,13,15},{4,2,2,2,2,2,3}))`

Comment: I was also thinking that cell format will not work. May be I have to go with `VBA` in `sheet_change` event.

Comment: For older versions of Excel: `=LEFT(A7,2)&TEXT(RIGHT(A7,15),REPT("00 ",6)&"000")`

Answer (score 1):

Excel stores only **15** significant digits in a number, and changes digits after the fifteenth place to zeroes.

Because custom number formats are designed to work primarily with numbers, you cannot create a custom number format that stores more than 15 digits.

[Microsoft.com - Last digits changed to zeros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/troubleshoot/excel/last-digits-changed-to-zeros)

You will need to bring in the 17 digit number as **text**.
Then split it to match your pattern by using a **formula**.

```
=CONCAT(LEFT(A7,4)," ",MID(A7,5,2)," ",MID(A7,7,2)," ",MID(A7,9,2)," ",MID(A7,11,2)," ",MID(A7,13,2)," ",RIGHT(A7,3))
```

Comment: With formula we can use `=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,MID(A7,{1,5,7,9,11,13,14},{4,2,2,2,2,2,3}))`.

Comment: I think, I have to go with `VBA` in `sheet_change` event.

Comment: Those arrays make the formula way more succinct.